# Tapestry5 : URL Re-writing : Pass parameters to transformPageRenderLink method

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tapestry

I am upgrading tapestry from 5.2.4 to 5.3.8 and am stuck at re-implementing the URL re-writing part.

In my application a user account can have multiple data stores. User can have same page of different stores active at the same time. Hence I need to put the storeId in page links and event links URLs. So What is done is as follows.

I register `MyLinkTransformerClass` in `AppModule` as follows.

```
    @Contribute(PageRenderLinkTransformer.class)
    @Primary
    public static void provideURLRewriting( OrderedConfiguration<PageRenderLinkTransformer> configuration){ 

       configuration.addInstance(
          "Faces", MyLinkTransformer.class);
    }
```

Following is the `MyLinkTransformer` class which implements `PageRenderLinkTransformer`

```
public PageRenderRequestParameters decodePageRenderRequest(
                  Request request) {

      // for incoming requests - remove the store id from URL and 
      // save into Request as an attribute

      String path = request.getPath();
      if (path.equals("/")) {
             // Redirect to accounts page
             return new PageRenderRequestParameters("account", new EmptyEventContext(), false);
         }
         else {
             String start = path.split("/")[1];
             if (!ignoredRewriteSet.contains(start) && !start.startsWith("account")) {
                 String storePath = path.substring(1).substring(path.indexOf("/"));
                 int idx = storePath.indexOf("/");
                 if (idx < 0) idx = storePath.length();
                 String storeId = storePath.substring(0, idx).trim();
                 RequestHelper.setStoreId(request, storeId);
                 EventContext urlEventContext = new URLEventContext(contextValueEncoder, new String[]{storeId});
                 EventContext arrayEventContext = new ArrayEventContext(typeCoercer, "foo");    
                 return new PageRenderRequestParameters(storePath.substring(idx), arrayEventContext, false);
                 //return new PageRenderRequestParameters(storePath.substring(idx), new EmptyEventContext(), false);
             }
     }

      return null;
    }

   public Link transformPageRenderLink(
         Link defaultLink,
         PageRenderRequestParameters parameters) {

      // for outgoing requests- This is where I want to access the store Id 
      // which is stored in Request class of Tapestry as an attribute and 
      // add it to the URL

      return null;
   }
```

**So, the idea is to remove storeId from URL in `decodePageRenderRequest` method and save it in the `Request` class of Tapestry as an attribute. And while creating outgoing URLs of page link and event link, I want to access the storeId which was saved in Request and inject it to the URL which will be rendered in method `transformPageRenderLink`.**

But I don't know how to pass parameters to `transformPageRenderLink` method or access `Request` instance there.

I am following http://blog.tapestry5.de/index.php/2010/09/06/new-url-rewriting-api/ example.
I am new to URL Rewriting, any help with this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably be interested in the ModeComponentEventLinkEncoder [here](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/uklance/mode/ModeComponentEventLinkEncoder.java). It removes a "mode" from the URL and puts it onto the [Environment](http://tapestry.apache.org/environmental-services.html) before passing it on to the normal tapestry URL processing.

It's a two way process so the "mode" is included in any links generated on the page.

Note: This is applied as a decorator [here](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/uklance/services/AppModule.java#L40)

Comment: Thanks for this! I dd use ModeComponentEventLinkEncoder but instead of storing the request in environment, I stored it into a session persistent variable "request" in transformer class. Issue with using environment was this. After receiving request, when page/event links are created for that page, environment.peek(Request.class) would return null, even though I did push the request in env while receiving it in decodeComponentEventRequest method.

Comment: You really shouldn't need the session for this as the information is bound to a single request. I'm not sure why you are peeking for Request.class. In my example you should peek(Mode.class). Pushing the Request onto the Environment / Session smells like very bad design to me. Putting a request on the session isn't valid since servlet containers re-use request objects. Or are you meaning some other custom Request class?

Comment: The code I inherited for v5.2.4 saved the data(storeId) in Request. Its the Request class of Tapestry. Now in v5.3.8, I think I can store storeId in environment using some DataContainer class. From incoming URLs, I will  get the storeId and save it in environment env.push(DataContainer.class) and for outgoing URLs I will access it using peek method. I need to see if there will still be the same issue which was there with env.peek(Request.class)

Comment: That sounds much better. Pushing the request onto the environment makes no sense. The request is a per-thread service and so is the environment. Pushing the request onto the http session is a terrible idea as I explained before, the servlet container may re-use these for another thread and cause all sorts of chaos.

Comment: FYI - there was an issue with ajax requests and the environment... I'm not sure if it's still an issue. In this case you might need to use request.setAttribute(...) like I had to do [here](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/stitch/components/TabGroup.java#L18)

Comment: You are right in your last comment. That issue is still there and in fact, this is the reason for the problem I described in my first comment. I am not able to use environment due to this. So, I am now storing the data in a data container class and data container is stored in session. That way I can at least avoid storing request in session.

Comment: NO!!!! Don't use the session!!!! Use a request attribute instead. There is absolutely no reason to persist this information between requests

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to access request in createPageRenderLink()/createComponentEventLink() method of transformer class implementing ComponentEventLinkEncoder interface. And its not a tapestry page class where I can inject the request. Is there a way I can access request in methods mentioned  above?

Comment: The Request is a service, just like any other tapestry service and can be injected via tapestry-ioc. It's exactly the same as the Environment.